# iOS ffmpeg how to run a command to trim remote url video?

Tags: ios, xcode, video, ffmpeg, avfoundation

I was initially using the `AVFoundation` libraries to trim video but it has a limitation that it can't do it for remote URLs and only works for local URLs.

So after further research I found `ffmpeg` library which can be included in a `Xcode` project for iOS.
I have tested the following commands to trim a remote video on command line:

```
ffmpeg -y -ss 00:00:01.000 -i "http://i.imgur.com/gQghRNd.mp4" -t 00:00:02.000 -async 1 cut.mp4
```

which will trim the `.mp4` from 1 second to 3 second mark. This works perfectly via command line on my mac.

I have been successfully able to compile and include `ffmpeg` library into a xcode project but not sure how to proceed further.

Now I am trying to figure out how to run this command on an iOS app using the `ffmpeg` libraries. How can I do this?

If you can point me to some helpful direction, I would really appreciate it! If I can get it resolved using your solution, I will award a bounty (in 2 days when it gives me the option).

Answer (score 0):

I have some idea about this. However, I have very limited exp on iOS and not sure whether my thought is the best way:

As far as I know, generally it is impossible to run the cmd tools on iOS. Maybe you have to write some code linked to ffmpeg libs.

Here's all the jobs needed to do:

1. Open input file and init some ffmpeg context.
2. Get the video stream and seek to the timestamp you want. This may be complicated. See [ffmpeg tutorial](http://dranger.com/ffmpeg/tutorial01.html) for some help, or check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17546073/how-can-i-seek-to-frame-no-x-with-ffmpeg) to seek precisely and dealing with the troublesome key frames.
3. Decode some frames. Until the frame match the end timestamp.
4. Meanwhile with above, encode the frames to a new file as output.

The examples in ffmpeg source is very good to learn how to do this.

Some maybe useful codes:

```
av_register_all();
avformat_network_init();

AVFormatContext* fmt_ctx;
avformat_open_input(&fmt_ctx, "http://i.imgur.com/gQghRNd.mp4", NULL, NULL);

avformat_find_stream_info(fmt_ctx, NULL);

AVCodec* dec;
int video_stream_index = av_find_best_stream(fmt_ctx, AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO, -1, -1, &dec, 0);
AVCodecContext* dec_ctx = avcodec_alloc_context3(NULL);
avcodec_parameters_to_context(dec_ctx, fmt_ctx->streams[video_stream_index]->codecpar)
// If there is audio you need, it should be decoded/encoded too.

avcodec_open2(dec_ctx, dec, NULL);
// decode initiation done

av_seek_frame(fmt_ctx, video_stream_index, frame_target, AVSEEK_FLAG_FRAME);
// or av_seek_frame(fmt_ctx, video_stream_index, timestamp_target, AVSEEK_FLAG_ANY)
// and for most time, maybe you need AVSEEK_FLAG_BACKWARD, and skipping some following frames too.

AVPacket packet;
AVFrame* frame = av_frame_alloc();

int got_frame, frame_decoded;
while (av_read_frame(fmt_ctx, &packet) >= 0 && frame_decoded < second_needed * fps) {
    if (packet.stream_index == video_stream_index) {
        got_frame = 0;
        ret = avcodec_decode_video2(dec_ctx, frame, &got_frame, &packet);
        // This is old ffmpeg decode/encode API, will be deprecated later, but still working now.
        if (got_frame) {
            // encode frame here
        }
    }
}
```